# Blurry digital signatures in letter of recommendation on letterhead

Tags: recommendation-letter

My referee has issued me a letter of recommendation on letterhead in hard copy form , but with very blurry digital signatures. The letter has the university stamp on it. There is contact number and address of the university's old campus, but with current university website mentioned on it. Moreover, the referee's email and phone number are not mentioned in the letter.

I am applying for a highly competitive scholarship. The referee has sent the letter in email to my abroad university supervisor. Now I need to apply using online application by uploading a scanned copy of the letter. In this scenario do you think that there is a chance of losing the opportunity because of the blurry signature, and lack of email and phone number of the referee?

Comment: What country is receiving the letter?

Comment: Country is Australia.

Comment: This is closely related to the asker's other recent question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/138125/letter-of-reference-without-referee-email-and-phone, adding in only the blurry signature.

Comment: Wikipedia says: `A digital signature is a mathematical scheme for verifying the authenticity of digital messages or documents`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

Answer (score 3):

The answer mainly depends on the pipeline of the scheme you are applying to. Without knowing their exact rules and regulations, it is not possible to answer your question exactly.

Having said that, if I received a LOR with signs of digital manipulation / forgery (such as blur signature), my first step would be to contact the referee directly. First, I would try to locate them online and use email / telephone from their official university page. Failing that, I would try email / number from the LOR. If it is absent, I would consider dropping the case, unless the rest of the evidence shows completely outstanding candidate.

Unfortunately, it is not uncommon to see forgery, lies and other dishonest ways of gaining advantage in academic applications. After all, Universities are reluctant or incapable to assign any penalty for this, encouraging such dishonest behaviour.  The duty of checking the paperwork falls down on academics appointed as "admission tutors" or "scholarship administrators", who usually do not have tools and time to perform rigorous checks. In case of doubt, they may decide to drop the application or at least de-prioritise it.

**tl;dr:** if your LOR looks forged, it may negatively impact your application.

Comment: If I take another letter of recommendation with appropriate sign and stamp, but without email and contact number on it. Would it work then? My university website does not have my refrees email.

Comment: Why don't you want to have your referee to put their email and contact number on the letter?