# Letter of reference without referee email and phone

Tags: recommendation-letter

My university has shifted to a new location. I have a letter of recommendation in hardcopy form on old letterhead (i.e., with the old campus address) but with the current date. Moreover, my letter of recommendation does not have the referee's email and phone. The website is present on the letter but the university website also does not have the same email address from which my referee has sent an electronic email to my supervisor in their university abroad.

Is it necessary to have the contact details of the referee in the letter of recommendation? Can it affect my opportunity negatively?

Answer (score 2):

People reviewing your application will want to be able to get in touch with your referee, one way or another (among other things, they may wish to request a copy of the recommendation directly from the referee rather than from you).

Normally, this is indeed included in the letter. If, as in your case, the letter of reference does not include this information (or the information is obsolete), there are two other simple places to include the correct information:

1. Some positions have a form for entering referee information.  In this case, you can enter all of the necessary contact information in that location, and possibly also a note on the change of location.
2. Your cover letter is the ultimate "exception handling" location; you can easily include a post-script with a note about the changed location and contact information.

Bottom line: while it's better to have the contact information correct in the letter, there are other simple ways to provide such information, and as long as it's easy to access and to understand what's going on, any reasonable hiring committee will not hold it against you.